# MySQL condition on the COALESCE syntax

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a query composing of COALESCE syntax. the COALESCE syntax simply find the Audited Date of a file. On my WHERE statement, I just want to output the Audited File base from the `AuditDate` alias field but i doesn't work. Here is my query.

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
 WHERE `AuditDate` BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

Can anyone help me on how should I get this query correct?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query need to be like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
 WHERE COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

for your situation you can't use the alias that came from a result of a function as query criteria in `WHERE` clause (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). But you can use the alias to search in `HAVING` clause, as MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit `HAVING` clause to refer to any column or alias named in a select_expr in the SELECT list or in outer subqueries, and to aggregate functions, like

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
 HAVING `AuditDate` BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

both have same result

Comment: thank you for the help, this query works fine and I don't need to create subquery.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
 WHERE COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

The above assumes that your date format/column types really match...

Comment: thank you for the help, this query works fine and I don't need to create subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an alias as others have pointed out. To avoid calling coalesce two times, you can use a HAVING statement.

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
HAVING `AuditDate` BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

Comment: thank you for the help, this query works fine and I don't need to create subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias from the `SELECT` list in the `WHERE` clause.

Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
           prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
           prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
           prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
      FROM production prd
      LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
        ON prd.id=qua.id
  ) AS tmp
WHERE `AuditDate` BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

or duplicate the code:

```
SELECT COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) AS `AuditDate`,
       prd.employeeno AS `EmployeeNo`,
       prd.starttime AS `StartTime`,
       prd.endtime AS `EndTime`
  FROM production prd
  LEFT JOIN qualityaudit qua
    ON prd.id=qua.id
 WHERE COALESCE(qua.starttime, prd.starttime) 
         BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-01 23:59:59';
```

Comment: thank you for the help, this query works fine and I don't need to create subquery.